# Заполнить форму на стороннем сайте при помощи локального javascript

Tags: javascript, автоматизация

Нужно автоматизировать заполнение и отправку форм на сайте объявлений посредством javascript. Вижу два варианта:

- Скачать страницу, распарсить токены защищающие от автоматического заполнения, отправить сформированный GET/POST запрос обработчику форм;
- Эмулировать действия пользователя на сайте: заполнение полей, нажатие на кнопку отправить.

Какой вариант универсальнее/проще? Есть ли готовые решения именно на javascript (а не браузерные плагины)?

Comment: Есть такая штука, как user-script.

Answer (score 1):

Запахло спамом... =/

Универсальнее/проще через POST, конечно, через curl и специальный ключ, который вам выделит владелец сайта ;) 
Но curl к js относится почти никак.

Вам остается таки да: эмулировать действия пользователя. И подозрений меньше будет.
GET и POST вам все равно не даст браузер отправить на левый сайт через JS, нужно чтобы JS принадлежал сайту или очень криво монтировать iframe.

В любом случае, капчу при помощи JS победить в автоматическом режиме почти нереально.

Comment: > капчу при помощи JS победить в автоматическом режиме почти нереально

отчего-же? зависит от ее сложности

Comment: @AlexWindHope, ага

    <img src="df36a.jpg" alt="df36a" title="captcha" />

Comment: Задача действительно на грани спама, но уж очень она монотонная и нетрудоемкая в автоматизации.
Капча, кстати, на раз распознается при помощи индусов и соответствующих сервисов =)

Думаю оформить решение на базе node-webkit в виде стороннего приложения. А как бы сделали Вы?